# Add add an object to a PFUser

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I try to add an object to a PFUser using the following code:

```
@IBAction func ButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    var user = PFUser.currentUser()
    user.addObject("test", forKey: "surname")}
```

But unfortunately I get no value on my Parse Dashboard. I don't understand why
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you save?

```
var user = PFUser.currentUser()
user.addObject("test", forKey: "surname")}
user.saveInBackground()
```

Also a couple notes.  You could use a `let` here as your user variable shouldn't change its pointer, and subscript syntax is more readable (my opinion) :)

```
let user = PFUser.currentUser()
user["test"] = "surname"
user.saveInBackground()
```

Comment: @Mansour - happens to everyone :)